# How can I put in each list the element that have the same id?

Tags: java, list

I want to put in each list the element that have the same id, and then bring all these lists into a single list, here is my table, as you can see on the picture "Image Result of SQL request" the id=1 is repeated so I want to have a Java list which contains just the elements that with the id = 1, and another Java list with the id=2......
 [Image Result of SQL request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9cZH.jpg)

[image]

Here is my incomplete code:

```
//Calculate Distance Traveled of a device in a specified 2 dates VERSION 2
public void  getDistanceTraveled2(Date StartDate,Date EndDate) {

    boolean exist=false;
    allDeviceList = (ArrayList<Device>) deviceBean.getListalldevice();// Get list of all device

    for(int i=0;i<allDeviceList.size();i++)
    {
        List<Eventdata> list = deviceBean.getLatAndLongDeviceId(); // get the id lat and long for each device
        List<Eventdata> list2 = new ArrayList<Eventdata>();

        while (list.size()!=0){


            String idCourant = list.get(i).getDevice().getDeviceid(); // get the first id
            String idNext = list.get(i+1).getDevice().getDeviceid(); // get the second id 

            if (idCourant == idNext)
            {
                //double distance = Point2D.distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                double  distance =  Point2D.distance(list.get(i).getLatitude(),list.get(i).getLongitude(),list.get(i+1).getLatitude(),list.get(i+1).getLongitude());//Calculate distance
                list2.add((Eventdata) Arrays.asList(idCourant, distance)); // store id and distance into a list
            }
            else {

                exist=true;
                break;
            }






        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `Map<Integer, List>`?

Comment: If your goal is to have the final, single list ordered by ID, can't you just add an `ORDER BY deviceid` to your SQL statement?

Comment: @daiscog , my objectif is to have a multipe list who have the date of every Device id and not a single list.

example : list1 must have the datat of id = 1 , list2 must have data of id=2....

Comment: In that case, a `Map<Integer, List>` is the way to go.  Incidentally, I notice that your `deviceid` SQL column is a `varchar`, not an `int` type; do any of the deviceids contain non-numerical values?  If they do, you'd need to use a `Map<String, List>`.  If they don't, you should consider changing the data type of that column to an `int`.

Comment: @daiscog ,  and how can calculate the distance for each device from this Map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Map with key as Integer and Value as List of ResultBean

```
Map<Integer, List<ResultBean>> map= new HashMap<Integer, List<ResultBean>>();
List<ResultBean> resultList = new ArrayList<ResultBean>();
// fetch data in rsultList by ID from table
map.put(1, new ArrayList<ResultBean>());
```

Comment: @Prakash: Note that you can use the [diamond syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond) to shorten the code a little: `new HashMap<>()`, `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Yes we can, but it is supported since java 7 only

Comment: @OthmaneBz , I beleive allDeviceList is type  ArrayList<Device> so you just need to iterate it

Comment: @OthmaneBz , Declare a resultMap Map<Integer, List<Device>> map= new HashMap<Integer, List<Device>>();

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma , and how can calculate the distance for each device from this Map ?

Comment: Override equals and hashCode in Device bean

Comment: and use Map<Integer, List<Device>> map= new HashMap<Integer, List<Device>>();
  for(Device device : allDeviceList){
   
   if(map.containsKey(device.getId())){
    List<Device> tempList = map.get(device.getId());
    tempList.add(device);
    map.put(device.getId(), tempList);
   }else{
    List<Device> tempList = new ArrayList<Device>();
    tempList.add(device);
    map.put(device.getId(), tempList);
   }
   
   
  }

Comment: to calculate distance iterate map by key, and get the devideList to iterate and calculate distance

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma , Ok its done , now how can we get all the latitude and longitude from the map to calculate the distance between the all latitude and longitude for each device by this function : double distance = Point2D.distance(x1, y1, x2, y2);

Comment: Point2D.distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) please confirm parameters ?? what is x1, y1, x2, y2

Comment: for(Integer deviceId: map.keySet()){
   List<Device> deviceListFromMap = map.get(deviceId);
   // Now iterate deviceListFromMap to get all values
   
  }

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma , i want to calculate the distance of latitude and longitude for each device at the end we will be able to know for exemple the distance traveld by device id = 1 and alsow the distance traveled by the device id = 2....
distance = Point2D.distance(latitude1, longitude1, latitude2, longitude2) 
and we need to recall this function every time when we had the same id
[ Image Result of SQL request][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/V9cZH.jpg

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma for example in the previous picture we have 4 column that have the id = 1 so we need to calculate all distance between the 4 column

Comment: So What my understanding  is , you need to calculate distance between row1 and row2 for ID=1 and then between row2 and row6 , Please confirm

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma , yes i want to calculate distance between row(1,2) and row (2,6) and row (6,9) for id = 1 , then i can have the distance traveled by the device id = 1

Comment: for(Integer deviceId: map.keySet()){
   List<Device> deviceListFromMap = map.get(deviceId);
   if(deviceListFromMap.size() > 1){
    for(int i=0; i < deviceListFromMap.size()-1; i++){
     Device div1=deviceListFromMap.get(i);
     div1.getId()
     Device div2 = deviceListFromMap.get(i+1);
     double  distance =  Point2D.distance(div1.getLat(), div1.getLongt(), div2.getLat(), div2.getLongt());
     //Save This distance for Device ID div1.getId()
    }
   }
   
  }

Comment: use these line of codes to iterate and calculate distance

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma My latitude and longitude is stored in a list<Eventdata> type and not in  List<Device> , i can get the device id for example by  : `List<Eventdata> tempList = map.get(eventData.getDevice().getDeviceid());`
and my device id is String and not Integer , can you please adjust your previous  code for me ?

Comment: Were you able to store device Id and Data as a List in Map

Comment: youare getting all data from this http://i.stack.imgur.com/V9cZH.jpg in Device bean or EventData bean ???

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma , from EvenData , here is my sql code to get this data : `select deviceid, latitude, longitude from Eventdata ORDER BY creationtime ASC`

Comment: @PrakashHariSharma , Ok its done ty so mush im waiting for your answer

Comment: List<EventData> allEventDataList;
  allEventDataList = (ArrayList<EventData>) EventDataBean.getListallEventData();// Get list of all EventData

Comment: Map<String, List<EventData>> map= new HashMap<String, List<EventData>>();
  for(EventData EventData : allEventDataList){
   if(map.containsKey(EventData.getDeviceid())){
    List<EventData> tempList = map.get(EventData.getDeviceid());
    tempList.add(EventData);
    map.put(EventData.getDeviceid(), tempList);
   }else{
    List<EventData> tempList = new ArrayList<EventData>();
    tempList.add(EventData);
    map.put(EventData.getDeviceid(), tempList);
   }
  }

Comment: for(String EventDataId: map.keySet()){
   List<EventData> EventDataListFromMap = map.get(EventDataId);
   if(EventDataListFromMap.size() > 1){
    for(int i=0; i < EventDataListFromMap.size()-1; i++){
     EventData div1=EventDataListFromMap.get(i);
     
     EventData div2 = EventDataListFromMap.get(i+1);
     double  distance =  Point2D.distance(div1.getLatitude(), div1.getLongitude(), div2.getLatitude(), div2.getLongitude());
     //Save This distance for EventData ID div1.getId()
    }
   }
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

generating list of every id is just too much and a O(n) considerable action..

instead create a "GeoDevice" Class wit id, lat, long and implement comparable
so you can sort by id.

then when you get the sql answer create one list of GeoDevices sort it and then 
use it to get all you need by browsing it by the ids in the objects...

Answer (score 0):

We can encapsulate the location data in a class named "Location".

```
class Location{
   private double latitude;
   private double longitude;

   public Location(double latitude, double longitude){
      this.latitude = latitude;
      this.longitude = longitude;
   }

  public String toString(){
     return this.latitude+","+this.longitude;
  }
}
```

Then we can store the data in a data-structure as follows:-

```
Map<Integer,List<Location>> locationData = new HashMap<>();  // Java 7 or above
```

[Data visualized in the above data-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoB52.png)